Air DatePicker - CSS from SkyPack
First time using SkyPack so I don't know if I'm missing something really obvious, but I'm trying to use Air DatePicker in a website.
I can get the code fine:
import AirDatepicker from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/air-datepicker';

new AirDatepicker('#adp');

I can see this working as it pops up loads of unstyled text for the control, however I cannot find the syntax / URL to get the CSS from Skypack.
Is there a Skypack or possibly CDN available CSS file for the picker?
As per Yogi's comment I have tried the below:
import AirDatepicker from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/air-datepicker';
import 'air-datepicker/air-datepicker.css' // Doesn't work

new AirDatepicker('#adp');

This throws an error Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "air-datepicker/air-datepicker.css". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
Here is a a JS Fiddle to demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/whelkaholism/4h95u2fp/
Click on the input as-is and you can see the popup; uncomment the css import and you'll get the error

Doesn't work; I have added a JSFiddle link to demo
